# create hyperlinks within VBscript array with variable output

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vbscript, asp-classic

In effort to redeem this question: **Updated edit below.**

```
<%
doMenu

    dim products
    dim manu
    dim website

    products = Array("E-reader set: Kindle Paperwhite, $119","Leather tote, $160","Earrings, $88","Skin care duo: Moisturizer, $62","Throw pillow, $90","Vitamix 5200, $449","Tea set: Le Creuset kettle, $1oo","Spring nail polish collection, $51","Framed birthstone print, $48","Cotton robe, $25","Jewelry box, $49","Water bottle, $35","Polka-dot scarf, $38","Makeup set: Eye palette, $44","Sequin pouch, $88","Ceramic set: Jar, $22","Honeycomb perfume, $54","3-jar jam set, $24","Recipe box, $34","Hair dryer, $200","Epicurious 11-piece cookware set, $320","Cookbook collection: 100 Days of Real Food by Lisa Leake, $20","Threshold dining set: Placemats, $10","Sodastream genesis, $90","Alexia necklace, $49","Wild & wolf garden tool set, $33","Rattan floor basket, $59","Olivia burton watch, $105","Yoga set: Mat, $40","Hair-care system: Restore shampoo, $28","")
    manu = Array("leather case, $40","","","eye serum, $48","","","three organic tea blends, $50","","","","","","","lip palette, $40; brush set, $50","","mug, $18; tray, $15","","","","","","Twelve Recipes by Cal Peternell, $20; Better on Toast by Jill A. Donenfeld, $20","$10; napkins","","","","","","bag, $20; towel, $25","conditioner, $28; mask treatment, $4","")

    website = Array("www.amazon.com","www.baggu.com","www.sarahhealydesign.com ","www.kiehls.com","www.Laylagrayce.com","www.vitamix.com","www.williams-sonoma.com","www.essie.com","www.minted.com","www.worldmarket.com","www.westelm.com","www.swellbottle.com","www.echodesign.com","www.maccosmetics.com","www.bodenusa.com","www.rosannainc.com","www.libraryofowers.com","www.murrayscheese.com","www.rifepaperco.com","www.shopt3micro.com","www.jcpenney.com", "www.amazon.com", "www.target.com", "www.surlatable.com","www.stelladot.com","www.burkedecor.com","www.landofnod.com","www.modcloth.com","www.gaiam.com","www.livingproof.com","")
%>
```

The above code populates content sections, in a single dynamic one-page website. **The problem is** the website outputs just the copy / text URL. **I need it to link, and preferably link out with a** `target="_blank"` for new window. I have tried the below; via an answered suggestion -- and while i think this may be better practice it doesn't seem to run with the other arrays, and breaks the site to resolve to a white page only. I've tried including it within my other array structures within same include and separate and breaks the site. I have also toggled the name of `arrUrls` to `website` and declared dim `arrUrls` etc etc and everything just broke the page so still need a solution.

```
dim arrUrls

arrUrls = Array("www.amazon.com","www.baggu.com")
For x=0 To UBound(arrUrls)
    currentUrl = arrUrls(x)
    Response.Write("<a href=""http://""" & currentUrl & """ target=""_blank"">" & currentUrl & "</a>")
Next
```

In the past I have done.. the below with jQuery arrays and would love a similar solution as something as inline and legible of this would be perfect.

```
     { value: "NYC", url: 'http://www.nyc.com' }, 
     { value: "LA", url: 'http://www.la.com' },
     { value: "Philly", url: 'http://www.philly.com' },
```

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the question? what is the intended output?

Comment: What do you want the array to be? Array of urls? Strings? Objects? HTML?

Comment: Just use an Array of Arrays like `website = Array(Array("www.amazon.com", "_blank"), Array("www.baggu.com", "_blank"))`. The array contains arrays with two elements website url and target, the second target can be accessed like so `target = website(1)(1)`.

Comment: @Lankymart interesting approach, but looks like OP here want a fixed target, so no need in this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<a href="http://<% response.write(website(day_part-1))%>" target="_blank" ><% response.write(website(day_part-1))%></a>
```

Including this inline alone with *only* variable output was most optimal and functional. This code alone, inline; without altering the array.

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying in my own answer, it's pointless to repeat it in a new answer.

Comment: No, your full snippet didn't work. And it broke my site. I had to use this alone.

Comment: I'm not sour, your code is a mess - mixing HTML and server side code. No idea why my exact code isn't working in your specific case, but if you want to improve it's really better for you to debug and find what happened, then fix it.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I found an answer on SitePoint only to include that line inline. I feel it's not the same answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't create the hyperlinks in the array. You create them in the code iterating the array:

```
<%
    Dim arrUrls, x, currentUrl
    arrUrls = Array("www.amazon.com","www.baggu.com")
    For x=0 To UBound(arrUrls)
        currentUrl = arrUrls(x)
        Response.Write("<a href=""http://" & currentUrl & """ target=""_blank"">" & currentUrl & "</a>")
        If x < UBound(arrUrls) Then Response.Write(" | ")
    Next
%>
```

Simple as that.

Comment: Inserting this breaks my website and turns the page white!!! And why did you add 'Next' at the end?

Comment: @Nooneknows you might have `Option Explicit` set, I've edited the code please try now. As for "Next", it's basic VBScript used for something known as "loop". You can learn about loops in any basic VBScript guide or tutorial, I just assumed you have some experience in this, guess I was wrong.

Comment: Thanks Bro, also update the question itself if it helps; trying to improve quality! @ShadowWizard

Comment: @Nooneknows sorry, no idea. I gave you just an example, not whole working code with what you need - you have to change it to fit your needs. As for "white page", probably error you have to configure IIS to send detailed error message so you can debug it.

Comment: @Nooneknows If you don't know why the `Next` is at the end it might be worth reading a Classic ASP / VBScript tutorial first.

Answer (score -1):

Using a sledge hammer to crack a nut:

```
Class LinkBuilder
'You could go with a dictionar or other name/value pair collection
'But we will keep this simple-ish

  Public Href
  Public Target
  Public CssClass
  Public Style
  Public Rel
  Public Id

  Public SetLink (iHref, iTarget, iClass, iStyle, iRel, iID)
       Href = iHref
       Target = iTarget
       CssClass = iClass
       Style = iStyle
       Rel = iRel
       Id = iID
  End Function

  Public GetOpenATag()
       Dim output;
       output = "<a href='" & Href & "'"

       if Target is not null and Target <> '' then
          output = output & " target='" & Target & "'"
       end if

       if Id is not null and Id <> '' then
          output = output & " id='" & Id & "'"
       end if

        'YOu get the Idea... do the same for the other properties
       output = output & " >" 
  End Function

End Class

'Now build your array of links 
Dim arrLinks()

arrLinks(0) = new LinkBuilder.SetLink("www.amazon.com", "_blank", "external", null, null, null)
arrLinks(1) = new LinkBuilder.SetLink("www.baggu.com", null, null, null, null, null)

'now to get a link

Dim aLink = arrLinks(0).GetOpenATag() & "Amazon</a>"
```

This is a very rough outline and completely untested. It should however give you something to work with. Also investigate the Asp dictionary object.

Comment: Not my downvote  but it's just way too complicated for something so simple. Kind of like having 100 lines just to print "hello world".

Comment: @ShadowWizard can't say I disagree, hence the "Using a sledge hammer to crack a nut" preface! Just thought I'd provide an option for the scenario where they might want to contain more info for the link. I just loath uncommented down votes.

Comment: Such warnings usually have no real effect... and downvotes are integral part of Stack Overflow, one just need to grow a thick skin over time. :)